# How to get summation with count larger than certain amount

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I want to have a sql that gives recipient that received of amount >= 1024, with number of transfer <=3.

e.g.,

[image]

The result is:

[image]

Johnson is listed since 
Johnson account is listed because it has received 1112 USD in the following three transfers: 512 USD + 100 USD + 500 USD, Taylor is with 1 transfer of USD 1024. Williams is not there since he receives 1200 in four transactions.

I try

```
Select recipient as account_name from transfers group by recipient 
having sum(amount)>=1024  and count(amount)<=3
```

It doesn't work correctly.
I am using PostgreSQL, SQLLites syntax is fine too.

Attached is the table and row creation for your convenient

```
 create table transfers (
      sender varchar(1000) not null,
      recipient varchar(1000) not null,
      date date not null,
      amount integer not null
  );

insert into transfers values('Smith','Taylor',convert(date,'2002-09-27'),'1024')
insert into transfers values('Smith','Johnson',convert(date,'2005-06-26'),'512')
insert into transfers values('Williams','Johnson',convert(date,'2010-12-17'),'100')
insert into transfers values('Williams','Johnson',convert(date,'2004-03-22'),'10')
insert into transfers values('Brown','Johnson',convert(date,'2013-03-20'),'500')
insert into transfers values('Johnson','Williams',convert(date,'2007-06-02'),'400')
insert into transfers values('Johnson','Williams',convert(date,'2005-06-26'),'400')
insert into transfers values('Johnson','Williams',convert(date,'2005-06-26'),'200')
```

Comment: Your SQL means that the person has had 3 or less transactions, not that the amount of 3 or less is more than 1024

Answer (score 9, accepted):

using `row_number()` and a derived table to limit each `recipient` to their top 3 amounts received, then grouping by `recipient` returning those having `sum(amount)>=1024`

```
select recipient as account_name
from (
  select * 
    , row_number() over (
        partition by recipient
        order by amount desc
        ) as rn
  from transfers
  ) as i
where rn < 4
group by recipient
having sum(amount)>=1024
```

returns:

```
+--------------+
| account_name |
+--------------+
| Johnson      |
| Taylor       |
+--------------+
```

rextester postgres demo: http://rextester.com/PFR74297

---

The question was edited that removed some pertinent information from the [3rd revision of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42608988/3): what was tried already.

> I try
>
> `Select recipient as account_name from transfers group by recipient`
>       `having sum(amount)>=1024  and count(amount)<=3`
>
> It doesn't work correctly.

Based on that information, I concluded that OP wanted to find `recipients` that received a `sum(amount)>=1024` from 3 or fewer of any of that recipient's transfers -- not limited to those recipients with 3 or fewer transfers and `sum(amount)>=1024`.

Comment: This answer is wrong. If a certain recipient receives multiple transfers, this will sum the 3 largest amounts, while the OP asked for names having had 3 or fewer transfers.

Comment: @Patrick I understand why you would think that my answer was wrong, but OP edited the question and removed some very important information. The reason I am taking the top three is because OP said `having sum(amount)>=1024  and count(amount)<=3` is not providing the results he wanted. I have rolled back the question to include that information again.

Comment: First of all, you should **never rollback an edit made by an OP** just to prove your point. Secondly, your answer does not adequately address the opening problem statement that was there all the time and neither does the text that the OP deleted but which you rolled back make your answer right. It is just plain wrong either way. As an established user on SO you should know and accept that your only viable course of action is to delete your answer; [Roman Tkachuk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42610273/3304426) provided a perfectly fine solution.

Comment: @Patrick You should not be making edits that vandalize a question, even if you are the OP such an edit is not okay.  It's entirely appropriate to rollback an edit that damages a question, regardless of who has made the edit.  The issue of the question edits is being [discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345009/rollback-etiquette-when-op-removes-code-from-question-after-your-answer-is-accep/345010#345010), if you would like to discuss this further, please do so there.

Comment: @Patrick - The OP asked for people with more than 3 transfers to be included - see the example provided and the reasons why Johnson should be included despite having 4 transfers, i.e. because Johnson has three transactions that, by themselves, add up to at least 1024.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you rather need this:

```
SELECT recipient
  FROM transfers
 GROUP BY 1
HAVING count(*) < 4
   AND sum(amount)>=1024
```

Answer (score 1):

Working solution with SQLite and without fancy functions :)

```
SELECT recipient AS account_name FROM 
    (
        SELECT transfers.recipient, SUM(transfers.amount) AS amountsum FROM transfers
        WHERE transfers.rowid IN (
                                      SELECT tmp.rowid FROM transfers tmp
                                      WHERE transfers.recipient = tmp.recipient
                                      ORDER BY tmp.amount DESC
                                      LIMIT 3
                                  )
        GROUP BY transfers.recipient
    )
WHERE amountsum >= 1024;
```