# How to compute a sum based on the 2 biggest values for each group (group by)?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

Let's say, I have this table below:

```
| Name     | Voters 
| George   | 10     
| Barack   | 20   
| Barack   | 50
| Barack   | 40
| Donald   | 30     
| Bill     | 20     
| George   | 10     
| Bill     | 30     
| Bill     | 15      
| Bill     | 10
```

I would like to get the sum of the 2 biggest numbers of Voters for each Name(or less)

```
| Name     | Sum2BiggestVoters 
| George   | 20 (10 + 10)
| Donald   | 30 (30)     
| Bill     | 20 (30 + 20; 10 and 15 are not considered not part of the 2 biggest numbers of voters for Bill)
| Barack   | 90 (50 + 40; 20 is not considered here for the same reason as above)
```

It looks a bit like this post: [How to get summation with count larger than certain amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608988/how-to-get-summation-with-count-larger-than-certain-amount/42609068), except that I am using SQLite which lacks the `row_number() over` feature as well as the `partition by`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pain in SQLite, because it doesn't support variables and it doesn't support window functions.  Assuming you have no ties for a given `name`, you can do:

```
select t.name, sum(t.voters)
from t
where t.voters in (select t2.voters
                   from t t2
                   where t.name = t2.name
                   order by t2.voters desc
                   limit 2
                  )
group by t.name;
```

Comment: works like a charm, except a typo at the end of the first where clause, you left a semicolon ";" and also I think it's better to leverage the rowid in that same "outer" where clause.